# Cannot access App class

Tags: laravel-5

I added a class in a new folder under the folder "app".

Inside this class I cannot access:

```
App::environment();
```

This does not work either:

```
\App::environment();
```

I am using this class in a script that I am running from command line.

I guess I am not bootstrapping the app correctly but I cannot figure out how.

Here is the calling script:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

use App\Scripts\SqlMigrator;

$sqlMigrator = new SqlMigrator();
```

I tried to import this in the class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
```

but then I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.'
```

Updating with what I got so far:

It seems close in the test class: When I use this:

```
$environment = app()->environment();
```

It gives me this error:

```
ReflectionException: Class env does not exist
```

Is this a hint for you?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to import app class as below

**`use App;`**

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that but I already tried that. it does not work.